# Как сделать чтобы Maven воспринимал указанную папку как ресурсы?

Tags: java, maven, resources

Подскажите, пожалуйста, никак не могу разобраться, вот есть у меня Maven проект, в нем  класс Main, в нем, например, такой код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(Files.lines(Paths.get("src/resources/one.txt")));
        System.out.println(Files.lines(Paths.get("src/resources/two.txt")));
    }
}
```

Как сделать так чтобы файлы которые я хочу прочитать были собраны в одну папку resources, но при этом путь можно было бы писать просто "one.txt", "two.txt", т.е. чтобы maven воспринимал resources как корневую папку?

Answer (score 0):

Можно указать `src/resources` как текущую рабочую директорию через параметр JVM `user.dir` например так:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("user.dir", "C:/путь-до-папки-проекта/src/resources");
        System.out.println(Files.lines(Paths.get("one.txt")));
        System.out.println(Files.lines(Paths.get("two.txt")));
    }
}
```

Того же эффекта можно добиться, передав `user.dir` при запуске приложения:

`java -Duser.dir="C:/путь-до-папки-проекта/src/resources" Main`

При этом ничего менять в pom.xml не нужно, если только вы не запускаете проект через Maven плагин.